# What is the 'me' in "masoretic text me" in the NIV note on Psalms 22:16?

Tags: textual-criticism, psalms, masoretic-text, niv

What is the 'me' in "masoretic text me" in the NIV note on Psalms 22:16?

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+22%3A16&version=NIV

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NIV footnote is simply stating that after the word “me,” “most manuscripts of the Masoretic text” read “like a lion.” The word “me” is actually in all manuscripts, as it is indicated by the pronominal suffix (*-ni*) at the end of the word הִקִּיפוּנִי (*hikkifuni*)—“encircle/enclose **me**,” which all manuscripts have. The actual textual variant is כארו v. כארי, “they dug” (or “pierced”) v. “like a lion.”

Comment: ah that must be it, they're saying most manuscripts after the word "me", have 'like a lion'.  I wouldn't say it's after "me,”(comma in quotes)  though since that screenshot shows a semicolon after me. like "me;"  So perhaps where you wrote `The NIV footnote is simply stating that after the word “me,”`  you should have said `The NIV footnote is simply stating that after the word “me”`  And where you wrote `“encircle/enclose me,”` you should have written `“encircle/enclose me”` ?

Comment: @barlop: I'm assuming Der Übermensch is following the American convention of [writing commas and periods inside quotation marks](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/quotation-marks/) even when they're not actually part of the quoted text. In any case, note that the Hebrew text has no such punctuation; it's inserted purely at the translator's discretion.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yeah I know the manuscripts don't include any such punctuation/diacritical marks. And neither does the translation here, So yeah I guess you're right that Der is using a (I think bizarre) american convention. of writing punctuation into quotation marks that aren't there in the (translation) text!